# Given a Bip38 encoded private key, Can you derive the address without knowing the password?

Tags: bip38

The title says it all. I have a private key that is BIP38 encrypted:

```
6PYVdYvBaMXD7bFNJwMh8DCTxcBQjzyPmqWDQDp2PBKYyFUACph7vzjeaN
```

Is there a way to derive the address from just that information?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be possible from reading the [BIP38 draft specification](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0038.mediawiki). However in this specific case, the key you have posted is a example from the [moneywagon python module documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/moneywagon/1.6.0). The password is `123` and the address is `1BrUfC75qyLQxxp7qcisfaMmwRMECo4ETC`.

Comment: I'd say _mathematically probable_, because it could be brute forced, but could take a very long time to be successful.